# How to implement OneSignal Push Notifications in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, onesignal

I want to implement push notifications in node js with the OneSignal package.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement OneSignal Push Notifications in Nodejs by following below steps:

1- First implement your OneSignal Push Notifications on the frontend side e.g (React Native, Reactjs, Flutter).

2- Then test those Push Notifications by sending manual notifications from One Signal website.

**Link for manual testing:** https://dashboard.onesignal.com/apps?page=1

3- If manual notifications are working then we are good to go on the Nodejs side. First Install "onesignal-node" package in your node App.

4- And use the below code to send notifications

```
   const sendPushNotificationsToAll = async (request, response) => {

  \\you can find app id and api key in your one signal 
   application settings

  const client = new OneSignal.Client(
  process.env.ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID,
  process.env.ONE_SIGNAL_API_KEY
  );

 const notification = {
 headings: { en: title },  ***title of notification***
 contents: {
  en: description,        ***description of notification***
  },
included_segments: ["Subscribed Users"],     ***target audience***
large_icon: "http://www.logo.com",     ***notification large logo***
big_picture: "http://www.bigpicture.com",    
data: {
  postId: postId,       ***fields data***
  },
};


 try {

 const res = await client.createNotification(notification);

response.status(200).json("Notification created successfully");
  } catch (error) {
response.status(500).json(error);
 }
};
```

Comment: This answer can be improved using the current OneSignal version @onesignal/node-onesignal